# Accessing user info in server javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I'm making a two player game where the users sign in with twitter. If I search in the console to see if there are users logged on ( `Meteor.users.find().count()` ) It returns the number of users ever to be logged in. After learning this I installed the userstatus package with meteorite. `db.users.find({'status.online' : true}).count()` using the terminal to start Meteor mongodb in my directory shows me the number of users currently connected. I have made a collection called games to start separate games for each two unique users. My guess for the next step is to search users and push them in to an array. I want to search if there is more than 1 user logged in and initialize a game if the right condition is met(2 users logged in). How do I check if there are enough users logged in instead of `db.users.find().count()` in my `if(Meteor.isServer){}` portion of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the github repo gives two examples, both in coffeescript, I converted them to Javascript using http://js2coffee.org/#coffee2js

https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

"You can use a reactive cursor to select online users either in a publish function or a template helper:"

Option One: Publish Function:

```
     Meteor.publish("userStatus", function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({
       "status.online": true
       }, {
       fields: {...}
    });
  });
```

Option Two: Template Helper:

```
Template.foo.usersOnline = function() {
   return Meteor.users.find({
     "status.online": true
  });
};
```